# Window.open location in a new tab opens once

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, location-href

I can successfully open location in a new tab through the following:

`window.open('','_blank').location.href=my_global_link;`

However, this would work fine on first click. The consecutive click opens the link on the same window as the one with the hyperlink. Why would it not open after the first try on a separate tab?

Comment: why first argument of `open` empty string?

Comment: Because `window.open('url','_blank')` didnt work for me

Comment: Shouldn't you do like this `window.open(my_global_link, '_blank');`

Comment: @Cyclone I did `window.open(my_global_link, '_blank');` and on the first click it opens in the new tab but on the second click it will load on the same page. What is the reason for that?

Comment: @Sarah - I don't know, perhaps something else in your code makes this happen. Try to add a name for the new window instead: `window.open(my_global_link, 'myWindow');`

Comment: ... + that name needs to be unique every time a new window is opened, otherwise the same window/tab is reused.

Comment: Nope.  Cyclone's answer is correct.  Here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cdhh7mg4/

Comment: @Cyclone yes you were right. There was a call being made elsewhere. Thanks